# How to use ng-repeat on <th> with ng-if (or ng-hide/ng-show)?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to achieve something like this :

```
<th>23/03 lundi</th>
<th>24/03 mardi</th>
<th>25/03 mercredi</th>
<th>26/03 jeudi</th>
<th>27/03 vendredi</th>

<th class="info"></th>

<th>30/03 lundi</th>
<th>31/03 mardi</th>
<th>01/04 mercredi</th>
<th>02/04 jeudi</th>
<th>03/04 vendredi</th>

<th class="info"></th>

<th>06/04 lundi</th>
<th>07/04 mardi</th>
<th>08/04 mercredi</th>
<th>09/04 jeudi</th>
<th>10/04 vendredi</th>

<th class="info"></th>

<th>13/04 lundi</th>
<th>14/04 mardi</th>
<th>15/04 mercredi</th>
<th>16/04 jeudi</th>
<th>17/04 vendredi</th>
```

(notice the `<th>` at the end of each week)

I've read about ng-if and also ng-hide/ng-show which could help there but I am not able to get it to work.

Here I am with this snippet :

```
<th ng-repeat="date in headers">
    {{date.date}} {{date.dayName}}
</th>
<th ng-show="date.dayName == 'vendredi'" class="info"></th>
```

This one obviously does not work because the second `<th>` is not in the scope of `ng-repeat` but I can't see how I can achieve this.

I also tried something else but it's not working which I understand since I still need to print the first `<span>` even if it's friday. Also as you can see, I struggle with the fact that this is not just about the content of the `<th>` but with the `class`.

```
<th ng-repeat="date in headers" class="active">
    <span ng-if="date.dayName != 'vendredi'">
        {{date.date}} {{date.dayName}}
    </span>
    <span ng-if="date.dayName == 'vendredi'">
        <th class="info"></th>
    </span>
</th>
```

Well, can anyone help ? I am seriously getting short on ideas here.

Comment: can you create another array similar to headers but add elements that are needed for "<th class="info"></th>".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ng-repeat seems great as it is...

Try to add a directive similar as this one:

```
.directive('calendarWeekend', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
        params: '=calendarWeekend'
    },
    link: function(scope, element){
        if(scope.params.date.dayName == 'vendredi' && scope.params.last != true) {
            element.after('<' + element[0].localName + ' class="info"></' + element[0].localName + '>');
        }
    }
  };
});
```

It will add a `<th class="info"></th>` after every `<th>` that contains 'vendredi'. Then it check if this is the last index of the ng-repeat so it avoids to add another useless `th.info`.

Finally, in your view, you can call your directive:

```
<th ng-repeat="date in headers" calendar-weekend="{date: date, last: $last }">
     {{date.date}} {{date.dayName}}
</th>
```

Comment: I had to add track by $index. It works perfectly now, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

The default ng-repeat format does not seem to support what you want directly, but we can tweak a little bit as shown in this plunker:

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/ZVIWdzNlzQnVzsEHa7TK?p=preview
```

The main idea is in controller, we bring in some scope variables to use in html:

```
$scope.list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]; // demo data, similar to your    headers
$scope.parseInt = parseInt;
var length = $scope.list.length + parseInt($scope.list.length/5);
$scope.range = new Array(length);
```

And the html part is then:

```
  <tr>
  <th ng-repeat="n in range track by $index">
    <span style="color:black;" ng-switch on="$index%6">
      <span ng-switch-when="5">
        info
      </span>
    <span ng-switch-default>
      {{list[$index-parseInt($index/6)]}}
     </span>
   </span>
  </th>
  </tr>
```

Comment: I've already tried that but it's resulting in a <th> inside a <th> which is not working.

Comment: You are right. In this case, you can make a copy of headers and insert new class="info" elements every 5 old date elements. When you do ng-repeat, use ng-show/hide. Another way is to use directive to wrap your table, so you can manipulate DOM easily.

Comment: Indeed I am currently working on a directive. It's working quite well but there is some other issue. Thank you for your answer anyway. :)